# Selenium takes > minute between commands

Tags: php, selenium-rc

Selenium seems to be pausing for about a minute between each step (I haven't seen less than 60 seconds).  Even steps that should be simple (like setSpeed) run at the same rate.

However, when I use the PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase class, I am able to run tests at normal speed.  (Also, the slow steps run fine on a coworker's computer.)

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks!

Here is the slow test:

```
debug_time(); // 0

require_once 'Testing/Selenium.php';
debug_time(); // 1

$s = new Testing_Selenium('*firefox', "http://google.com/");
debug_time(); // 2

$s->setSpeed(0);
debug_time(); // 3

$s->start();
debug_time(); // 4

var_export($s->getSpeed());
echo "\n";
debug_time(); // 5

$s->open('/');
debug_time(); // 6

$s->stop();
debug_time(); // 7

echo "done";
```

Here is the output for the slow test:

```
0 => 18:01:54.44488 (+ 0.00000)
1 => 18:01:54.45478 (+ 0.00990)
2 => 18:01:54.45645 (+ 0.00167)
3 => 18:02:54.97334 (+ 60.51688)
4 => 18:04:03.59346 (+ 68.62013)
NULL
5 => 18:05:04.11214 (+ 60.51867)
6 => 18:06:05.83747 (+ 61.72534)
7 => 18:07:06.63492 (+ 60.79744)
done
```

Here is the fast test, taken from the PHPUnit manual:

```
require_once 'PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php';

class WebTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase
{
    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->setBrowser('*firefox');
        $this->setBrowserUrl('http://google.com/');
    }

    public function testTitle()
    {
        $this->open('/');
        $this->assertTitleEquals('Example Web Page');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same here. Downgrade to Testing_Selenium-0.4.3 helped. Trying to find the reason. May be PHP5.3?

Comment: Well, that definitely worked. Thanks! As for the reason, my coworker is on 5.3 and he hasn't had any trouble. It would be great to know if you figure anything out about the cause.

Comment: Same trouble here. php 5.3 and Testing_Selenium-0.4.4 hat a pretty much exactly 60 seconds timeout even when specifying a tiny timeout in the constructor. Downgrading to 0.4.3 helped indeed. 0.4.3 is frim 2008-07-15 though. I wouldn't complain if anyone diffed the versions looking for hardcoded timeouts ;)